# ColdFusion not recognizing comma delimiters

Tags: forms, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a form with checkboxes that need to be processed 
I want to loop through each selected option but I can't seem to make ColdFusion recognize the HTML checkbox fields as a list

So if someone selected option 1 and 2 I should be able to loop through the comma separated list of submitted values . however it keep selecting the whole string as a single entry, despite the comma delimiters

Example:

```
<form action="" method="get">
<input name="test" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" />Option1<br>
<input name="test" type="checkbox" value="2" checked="checked" />Option2<br>
<input name="test" type="checkbox" value="3" checked="checked" />Option3<br>
<input name="test" type="checkbox" value="4" checked="checked" />Option4<br>
<input name="" type="submit" />
</form>


<cfif IsDefined("test")>
<cfoutput> lenght: #len(test)#<br>
#test#
</cfoutput><br />
<cfloop index="i" list = "#test#" delimiters="," >           
        <cfoutput>#i# ---#test#<br /></cfoutput>
</cfloop>
</cfif>
```

returns:

```
lenght: 7 
1,2,3,4 
1 ---1,2,3,4
2 ---1,2,3,4
3 ---1,2,3,4
4 ---1,2,3,4
```

(I'm using ColdFusion 10 dev edition)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are misreading your code. It's working:

1. exactly as expected;
2. exactly as you want it to!

When you reference `form.test`, it will be a list of all the values you have selected in the checkboxes. EG: if you've checked them all, then the value will be `1,2,3,4`

You are demonstrating this to yourself with this bit of your code:

```
 <cfoutput>#i# ---#test#<br /></cfoutput>
```

You're seeing `---1,2,3,4`. IE: `form.test` contains `1,2,3,4`

When one loops over a list like this:

```
<cfloop index="i" list = "#test#" delimiters="," >
```

Then `i` will take each element *value* of the list in turn. And you are also seeing this.

And the length of `form.test` is indeed `7`: `"1,2,3,4"` is seven chars. `listLen()` would give you `4`.

Finally, some coding suggestions:

- scope your variables: `form.test` not `test`
- do not use `isDefined()`, use `structKeyExists()`
- I know this is sample code, but `i` is a poor variable name in this context (and probably confusing you), `checkBoxValue` might be better. Or something that indicates what the checkbox represents.
- if your delimiter is a comma, you do not need to specify it in list operations (functions, loops, etc). Comma is already the default.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it correctly. You have to use variable in INDEX attribute (i in this case). If your CHECKBOXES has values of 23,12,78,56. Then I would return those values in each iteration. Look like you are being confused with "i" giving iteration counter value.

Comment: if I was not clear, just change the values of checkboxes to some random number, you will get the more clear picture :)

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem here? Firstly the length is 7, because you're treating it as a string by using the len() function.

If however you want to find out how many list items are in it, you can use [ListLen](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ListLen) instead e.g.
`length: #listlen(test)#`

Secondly are you trying to get the value of each list item as you loop over it?  By outputting `#test#` each time you're just outputting the entire list.  Instead you can simply output `#i#`

Comment: When looping over a list like that, `i` is the element, not the index. So no need for a `listGetAt()`... you've already got it!